# Printing data normally without Array of arrays in spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have below sample of data :

```
67832,CLARE,MANAGER,68319,1991-06-09,2550.00,,1001
65646,JONAS,MANAGER,68319,1991-04-02,2957.00,,2001
```

I want to get data where last column data is `NOT EQUAL to 2001.` So I tried below steps

1) Loaded data in RDD:

```
val employeesRdd=sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/Employees/employees.txt").filter(p=>{p.length > 0 && p!=null})
```

2) Performed transformation:

If I modify my code like below then it gives array of array of strings but I want it to be printed like the normal data as the input dataset.

```
employeesRdd.map(_.split(",")).filter(p=>!(p(7)="2001")).collect
```

3) Even I tried mapping it with case class but got output as shown below:

```
case class employees(emp_id:java.lang.Long,emp_name:String, job_name:String,manager_id:java.lang.Long,hire_date:String,salary:java.lang.Double,commision:java.lang.Double,dep_id:java.lang.Long);

val employeesRdd1=employeesRdd.map(_.split(",")).map(p=>employees(if(p(0).length>0)p(0).toLong else 0L,p(1),p(2),if(p(3).length>0) p(3).toLong else 0L,p(4),if(p(5).length>0) p(5).toDouble else 0D, if(p(6).length>0) p(6).toDouble else 0D,if(p(7).length>0)p(7).toLong else 0L)).toDF()  

employeesRdd1.foreach(println):
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT OF DATA AFTER MAPPING:

```
employees(67832,CLARE,MANAGER,68319,1991-06-09,2550.00,,1001)
employees(65646,JONAS,MANAGER,68319,1991-04-02,2957.00,,2001)
```

How to access elements in such cases. I tried below sample code as well but it throws an `error that _1 is not a member of String`:

```
employeesRdd1.map(_._1).first
```

So the whole point is I want to print in a normal form like the input data but without records that have last column != 2001. So where am I going wrong ?? Or is it ok if data is printed in Array of Array form ?? Is it valid from certification perspective ?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Finally after hard fought battle I found the solution to my problem. Below is the working code:

1) Create `case class`:

```
case class employees(emp_id:java.lang.Long,emp_name:String, job_name:String,manager_id:java.lang.Long,hire_date:String,salary:java.lang.Double,commision:java.lang.Double,dep_id:java.lang.Long);
```

2) Load RDD:

```
val rdd=sc.textFile("file:////home/cloudera/Desktop/Employees/employees.txt").filter(p=>{p!=null && p.trim.length>0})
```

3) Map case class with the RDD:

```
val employeesDf=rdd.map(_.split(",")).map(p=>employees(if(p(0).length>0)p(0).toLong else 0L,p(1),p(2),if(p(3).length>0) p(3).toLong else 0L,
p(4),if(p(5).length>0) p(5).toDouble else 0D, if(p(6).length>0) p(6).toDouble else 0D,if(p(7).length>0)p(7).toLong else 0L))
```

4) Apply Transformation:

```
employeesDf.filter(_.dep_id!=2001).foreach(println)
```

I also appreciate the efforts of the other people who tried their best to help me out. Cheers !

Comment: As I said in other post as well, I am doing this from certification perspective and there is no inbuilt api for reading csv file in spark 1.6, sir

Comment: I believe in certifications, you are allowed to download external resources via `--packages` on `spark-submit`. Though, my certifications never covered Spark (because you can use any tool to get the expected output)

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity you can just add one more `&&` expression in your initial expression as

```
val employeesRdd=sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/Employees/employees.txt").filter(p=>{p.length > 5 && p!=null && !p.substring(p.length-5).contains("2001")})
employeesRdd.foreach(println)
```

will give you

```
67832,CLARE,MANAGER,68319,1991-06-09,2550.00,,1001
```

from the given input and you don't have to go through all the case class stuffs because your final requirement is

> > the whole point is I want to print in a normal form like the input data but without records that have last column != 2001

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Yeah but what I think is this solution won't help always since length of records may vary for each and every record. Am I correct ?

Comment: yes you are correct and I have already suggested you to go for array stuff. thanks for the upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below snippet:

```
val testRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile("D://testsample.txt");

case class employees(emp_id: Long, emp_name: String, job_name: String, manager_id: 
Long, hire_date: String, salary: Double, dep_id: String);

val depRDD = testRDD.map(_.split(",")).map(p => employees(p(0).toLong, p(1), p(2), 
p(3).toLong, p(4), p(5).toDouble, p(6))).filter(!_.dep_id.equals("2001"));

depRDD.foreach(println)
```

This will give you all the rows which does not have dept_id 2001.The "!" operator in the filter function will return true when dept_id is not 2001. The sample input I consider is given below:

```
67832,CLARE,MANAGER,68319,1991-06-09,2550.00,1001
65646,JONAS,MANAGER,68319,1991-04-02,2957.00,2001
23459,SAMIK,MANAGER,68319,1991-08-12,2550.00,3001
67890,SUMAN,MANAGER,68319,1991-06-23,2957.00,2001
```

Comment: I tried your code but it throws exception along with the data because of which when I try to save data in to text file it throws error and doesn't write data. Please refer imgur.com/a/EEkDNtz

Comment: I referred the link imgur.com/a/EEkDNtz. It seems you are neither using my code nor the input text file which I shared on the above answer. Please try it.

Comment: yeah ,I got the same output for your answer as well thats why I shared the same screenshot which I attached in the above answer

Comment: Did you use the same input file which I shared!!